# simplifying nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I have below code to get `result` from `func1` using `callback1`. But `func1` is using `func2` with `callback2` and then depends on that second callback either returns `result` or using `func3` with `callback3` to get `result`. Not sure where to put another callback to get one `result`.

```
module1.func1(arg1, function (callback1) {
    module1.func2(arg2, function (callback2) {
        if (result2) result = result2;
        else
        module2.func3 (arg3, function (callback3) {
            result = result3;
        })
    })
});
```

If I add another callback to `func3` it will work only in case I don't get result from `func2` immediately. Maybe that's all I need , pattern looks too complex for me

```
module.exports = function (callback) {
    module1.func1(arg1, function (callback1) {
        module1.func2(arg2, function (callback2) {
            if (result2) result = result2;
            else
                module2.func3 (arg3, function (callback3) {
                    result = result3;
                    callback(result) //???
                })
        })
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested callback hell can in be tackled in recent JavaScript versions by promisses. One of many resources on the net is

https://github.com/mattdesl/promise-cookbook

Promisses are available in ES6, but also several libraries. I hope this gives you an idea what to look for.